# MVC 4: Every F5 on First Time Login Always Won't Work, it will Only Work After the First Time

Tags: c#, jquery, json

As mentioned in the title, i cannot login everytime for the first time, but subsequent time I can login, where is wrong?Any Help will be appreciated! Or any new ways to implement the code? I'm new to it, it will also serve as a learning experience to me :)

Also is there any way in Razor to make Url.Action to string url instead of Object?

```
jQuery Client Side:
//To be submitted to the server for authentication
<script>
    $(".btn").click(function () {
        login();
    });
    function login() {
        var username = $("#username").val();
        var password = $("#password").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            //url: "/member_control.asmx/Login",
            url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: '{"username": "' + username + '","password": "' + password + '" }',

            success: function(result) {
                if (result.Success) {
                    window.location.href = result.redirectToUrl;
                } else {
                    alert(result.Message);
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>


       Json Server Side:  
        //json will be returning back to the jquery request

            [AllowAnonymous]
            [HttpPost]
             public JsonResult Index(LoginModel1 model, Object redirectToUrl){
            //set default
            redirectToUrl = Url.Action("Test", "Home");

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (DataAccess.DAL.UserIsValid(model.Username, model.Password))//Authentication
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Username, false);
                    return Json(new { Success = true, redirectToUrl = Url.Action("Test", "Home") });
                }
                {
                    return Json(new { Success = false, Message = "Login failed, invalid username or password." });
                }
            }
            return Json(new { Success = false, Message = "Login failed" });
    }
```

Comment: Is the client given any cookies to hold after a successful login?

Comment: isn't this: FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Username, false); for creating cookie?

Comment: Yes, but is that cookie being given to the server every time the page is reloaded?

Comment: Hmmm... how to check it?

Comment: Well, if you are ALWAYS logging in through AJAX posts, it should be in your JavaScript.  You really should be POSTing this login data...

Comment: Well, from the code above, I do not have it in the ajax, how should I do it then?

Comment: Is your javascript at the bottom of your page? If not you'll need to wrap it in `$(function(){ //your code });`

Answer (score 0):

Well this is not recommended to logged in via ajax but in your case the problem might be because of caching. Add an option `cache : false` in your current jquery ajax request and problem will be resolved.

**Example :**

```
 $.ajax({
    cache : false,
    // existing stuff
 });
```

Comment: Fast reply, but unfortunately, it didn't work still. If it is not recommended, what do you suggest that I do? Is there any other jquery that can pass to json other than using ajax?

Comment: If you want to post the form via ajax i would recommend use **[Ajax.BeginForm in MVC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions.beginform%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)**

Comment: but what if I'm using twitter bootstrap, how am I going to implement this into it?

Comment: One more thing that i found in your controller action is that you didn't decorate it with **[HttpPost]** attribute. Try adding this attribute and check it again.

Comment: hmmm, I had previously added it but forgotten to put in the post. It didn't work though.